# Need help comparing the mass of predicted and experimented Higgs Boson mass

Tags: particle-physics, higgs

I have been researching for countless hours and I can not find any relevant information on calculated/predicted Higgs Boson mass for my physics report. I have looked into super-symmetry, breaking symmetry and academic papers which was incomprehensible.

If someone could point me in the right direction for a year 12 (final year) towards finding relevant information for calculated/predicted mass for Higgs Boson would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hello. For this kind of information, you could look up the [Higgs Boson Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_boson). I suggest you read that first and come back to this post if you have any doubt.

Comment: There was a not a specific predicted value, just a rather wide allowed range. See https://news.fnal.gov/2010/07/fermilab-experiments-narrow-allowed-mass-range-higgs-boson/